# What does <input type="file">create, a FileUpload Object or a FileList?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, file-io, filelist

In the HTML file, I wrote:

```
<input type="file" id="xmlfile" onchange="handleFiles(this)"/>.
```

W3School says that "For each  tag in an HTML form, a FileUpload object is created." And I indeed succeeded in getting the path of the file by using the code following in JS script:

```
function handleFiles(iFile){ var path = iFile.value; }
```

But there is another opinion that `<input type="file">` returns a FileList. 
I am confused. If it returns a list of files, there are also a list of paths. In this case, what does "iFile.value" mean ? A list of paths of files ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [w3fools](http://w3fools.com) says many things. Occasionally they may even be right, the same was a broken clock is correct twice a day.

Comment: In your case, you're allowing a single file to be uploaded. Therefore, the `value` property is the filename of that file. If you added `multiple="multiple"` to your tag, you'd be allowed to select multiple files (in browsers that support it). If you select multiple, the result of `iFile.value` would be the first selected file's filename. If you wanted to access all files selected in that case, you can loop through the `iFile.files` collection (in browsers that support it), which is the `FileList` (you can treat it as an array). You can still access `iFile.files` without the `multiple` attr

Comment: Thanks Lan and Talisfang, both your answers are helpful. In fact,    iFile itself is a FileUpload Object. [tag:FileList] is returned by [tag:iFile.files]. I've tried it and it is true. Here is an explanation given by Mozilla : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FFileList

Answer (score 1):

`console.log(object)` is the function that I used to see the objects of Javascript in Chrome developer tools.

```
  function handleFiles(iFile) {
            var path = iFile.value;
            console.log(iFile);
            console.log(path);
  }
```

Here is  the output:

```
<input type="file" id="xmlfile" onchange="handleFiles(this)">
C:\fakepath\README
```

From here we can say that `<input type="file">` or `iFile` parameter returns a FileUpload object and `iFile.value` is the path that is chosen to be uploaded.